# wxpython control similar to tabbed panes

Tags: wxpython

Is there any Wxpython control that looks like a tabbed panels...I can use notebook but im not able to close the pages..I need something similar to IE, where you can open new tabs and close it when not needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the agw.flatnotebook.

Answer (score 0):

While the FlatNoteBook is a good choice, I think the agw.aui.AuiNotebook is better:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/AuiNotebook%20%28AGW%29
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/09/the-%E2%80%9Cbook%E2%80%9D-controls-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/